# How do I generate A-Z randomly to fill an array?

Tags: arrays, random, 2d

My assignment is to create a 3 part program which when you press 1, it runs method or "feature" 1, when you press 2, it runs feature 2, press 3, it runs feature 3.  The end.  I have the second feature figured out, but this feature (feature 1) is supposed to generate A-Z randomly to fill a 10x20 array.  The code AS IS generates random integers and correctly fills and DISPLAYS a 10 x 20 grid.  HOWEVER, how do I get it to display A-Z characters instead of numbers?

```
public class ModuleOnefor8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = new int[10][20];

        for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*'Z'-'A' + 1);

                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
public static String numberToAlpha(int number)
{
    char[] ls = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();

    String r = "";

    while(true)
    {
        r = ls[number % 26] + r;

        if(number < 26) {
            break;
        }

        number /= 26;
    }

    return r;
}
```

Use:

```
int min_int = 1;
int max_int = 9999;

string out_alpha = MyClass.numberToAlpha( Math.random() * ( max_int - min_int ) + min_int );
```

Comment: Does this randomly fill the array with the letters?  I apologize but everyone seems to give me help as though I am a programmer just trying to learn another language.  I get lost easily and don't understand things like what you just wrote, even though I'm sure it is probably exactly what I need, but I don't know where to put that code in my program, because it doesn't look anything like what I have learned so far.  I took an Intro to Programming course before this, and arrays bit me there too.

Comment: In this case only show you: Generating random alpha... Use this new function at code line 6. If you want out new function in same class of your code